# Login através de um subdominio

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou com um problema pra resolver.
Tenho uma rede social, e tenho um bate papo do boom chat, a rede social é wowonder.

Eu estou integrando o sistema de login da rede social no boom chat, porem quando eu tento fazer o login, pela tela do boom chat que está em um subdominio, acontece o seguinte:

estou utilizando a mesma função da rede social para isso, exemplo, eu estou fazendo um request para o arquivo dentro da rede social, que é responsavel pelo login da rede social, e estou consultando pelo subdominio do boom chat, então coloco o email e senha e clico em ok, ele faz a requisição e leva direto para a rede social, só que não vai logado, ele vai pra tela de login da rede social, que por sua vez é a mesma index, deveria estar logado.

Bom, eu acho que não está criando uma sessão pelo fato de eu estar tentando logar pelo subdominio. Então eu queria saber como eu faço pra que eu consiga logar pelo chat, sendo que eu preciso ser redirecionado pra rede social?

Códigos:

```
<script>
var working = false;
var $this = $('#login');
var $state = $this.find('button > .state');
var login_button_text = '<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login';
$(function () {
    $('#login').ajaxForm({
        url: 'https://ghender.com/requests.php?f=login',
        beforeSend: function () {
            working = true;
            $this.addClass('loading');
            $state.html('autenticação');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.status == 200 || data.status == 600) {
                $this.addClass('ok');
                $state.html('Bem vindo de volta!');
                setTimeout(function () {
                   window.location.href = "https://ghender.com";
                    //window.location.href = data.location;
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                var errors = data.errors.join("<br>");
                $state.html(login_button_text);
                $this.removeClass('ok loading', function () {
                    $state.html(errors);
                });
            }
            working = false;
        }
    });
    $('#login input').on('click', function (e) {
        $state.html(login_button_text);
    });
});
```

```
if ($f == 'login') {
$data_ = array();
$phone = 0;
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = Wo_Secure($_POST['username']);
    $password = Wo_Secure($_POST['password']);
    $result = Wo_Login($username, $password);
    if ($result === false) {
        $errors[] = $error_icon . $wo['lang']['incorrect_username_or_password_label'];
    } else if (Wo_UserInactive($_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors[] = $error_icon . $wo['lang']['account_disbaled_contanct_admin_label'];
    } else if (Wo_UserActive($_POST['username']) === false) {
        $_SESSION['code_id'] = Wo_UserIdForLogin($username);
        $data_ = array(
            'status' => 600,
            'location' => Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=user-activation')
        );
        $phone = 1;
    }
    if (empty($errors) && $phone == 0) {
        $userid = Wo_UserIdForLogin($username);
        $ip = Wo_Secure(get_ip_address());
        $update = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "UPDATE " . T_USERS . " SET `ip_address` = '{$ip}' WHERE `user_id` = '{$userid}'");
        $session = Wo_CreateLoginSession(Wo_UserIdForLogin($username));
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $session;
        setcookie(
                "user_id", $session, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
        );
        $data = array(
            'status' => 200
        );
        if (!empty($_POST['last_url'])) {
            $data['location'] = $_POST['last_url'];
        } else {
            $data['location'] = $wo['config']['site_url'];
        }
    }
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
if (!empty($errors)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'errors' => $errors
    ));
} else if (!empty($data_)) {
    echo json_encode($data_);
} else {
    echo json_encode($data);
}
exit();
}
```

Aguardo respostas, e tiro as dúvidas.

Comment: Alisson peço que insira um código mínimo ou completo que contempla o problema, como é feito a `session` pelo `wowonder` qual o tipo de criptografia?

Comment: Pronto esses códigos são os códigos que o wowonder utiliza para login, eu apenas peguei o javascript e coloquei no boom chat, e é claro eu modifiquei a url

Comment: Ninguém para orientar?

Comment: Pode haver vários fatores que podem criar rotas no login dentro do `wowonder`, algum require em expecifico que no chat não está sendo chamado, se o `wowonder` foi desenvolvido sobre algum framework ou em php puro em `MVC` podem haver algum controller ou classe que seta algumas variáveis na session ou no banco, que no caso ao copiar o código o mesmo não funcione em outro diretório.

Comment: Imagino, eu andei analisando e estou pensando colocar o chat em uma pasta, e não em um subdominio, talvez eu consiga criar uma sessao, dentro da pasta principal do site